# Wifi not working after today's (14 July 16) update

Tags: drivers, wireless, updates, 15.04, broadcom

Today I had an Ubuntu update. After I restarted, I noticed the wifi no longer works.

In System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers, I noticed that under the Broadcom wireless network adapter, it says "This device is not working." So I tried

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then when I try

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I get the following

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  bcmwl-kernel-source
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/inaddy/lp1415880/ubuntu/ vivid/main bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu3~lp1415880~1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/inaddy/lp1415880/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu3~lp1415880~1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So then I try sudo apt-get update, which gives

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://archive.scrapy.org scrapy InRelease                                 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease                        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease                       
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com vivid InRelease                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports InRelease                     
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid InRelease                                   
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com vivid Release.gpg                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid InRelease                                   
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com vivid Release                                     
Get:1 http://linux.dropbox.com vivid/main amd64 Packages [1,148 B]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid InRelease                                   
Get:2 http://linux.dropbox.com vivid/main i386 Packages [1,148 B]              
Hit http://archive.scrapy.org scrapy/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.scrapy.org scrapy/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://archive.scrapy.org scrapy/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://archive.scrapy.org scrapy/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Sources                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Sources               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Sources        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Sources               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main amd64 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted amd64 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe amd64 Packages          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main i386 Packages               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe i386 Packages           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Translation-en              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main amd64 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Translation-en          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Sources  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse Sources
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Sources                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Sources     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Sources       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Sources     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse i386 Packages   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-en
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com vivid/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Translation-en  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-en  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Sources 
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com vivid/main Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Sources   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Fetched 2,296 B in 4s (552 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/inaddy/lp1415880/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/inaddy/lp1415880/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: During the updates, did you get the prompt about turning off Secure Boot?  Did you decide to leave Secure Boot enabled?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't remember anything about Secure Boot during the updates.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is not supported.

Comment: @Pilot6 I realized that last night. I'll install 16.04 today

Comment: Not sure if related, but I installed the latest updates this morning (some kernel update, I believe, had to restart), and wireless was totally broken afterwards. I run 14.04 on a Dell XPS 13 DevEdition which should have an Intel Wireless card. There have been [similar reports](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/t/19985774) on the Dell forum.

Comment: @BasSwinckels I'm running Dell XPS 13 too. I just upgraded to 16.04 and the wireless is still broken.

Comment: Ahhh, it didn't work because I didn't ` sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` after my fresh install. It works now, after I installed the driver and turned off secure boot.

Comment: Should I delete this question? It is no longer relevant

Comment: @AlanC A work-around that works for me (as suggest on the Dell forum) is to boot into an older kernel version (I had to set GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=-5 to make the Grub menu appear, see instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version). I tried to sign up for the Dell forum to join the discussion there, but also that is broken :(.